# Firewalld not saving ports, but show success, info in the config but not in --list-all

Tags: firewalld

Just completed a few tomcat servers that sit behind an LB, everything worked fine with the firewall off, so I enabled `firewalld` and added my ports for the cluster. All of the servers except for one worked just fine. For some reason, on one of the servers it will not show the ports when I do `firewall-cmd --list-all` but it does actually show the ports in `public.xml` inside the firewalld etc directory. Here is the same command that I used for all servers:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=4000-4100/tcp
```

After running that I get `success`. Yet, I get the following when I run `firewall-cmd --list-all`

```
public (default, active)
  interfaces: ens32
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 45564/tcp 8080/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

The other ports that I put in there stay without any issues (that's the 45564 and 8080)

What's weird is when cat `/etc/firewalld/public.xml` it shows the ports in there.

```
<zone>
 <short>Public</short>
 <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
 <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
 <service name="http"/>
 <service name="ssh"/>
 <port protocol="tcp" port="45564"/>
 <port protocol="tcp" port="4000-4100"/>
 <port protocol="tcp" port="8080"/>
</zone>
```

Some of the times that I entered in the command to allow 4000-4100, they would actually show in the `--list-all` but if I restarted the firewall, they would not show back up (the others would).

Having some issues resolving this. Any help ya'll might have, I would greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should runn the command

## firewall-cmd --reload

after you executed commands with "--permanent". Those commands work only on the config file but not on the current running configuration. IF you do not use --permanent,
you are working on the running configuration and can see you changes immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I hate when I come across the one post that mentions my exact problem and there are zero replies, so here it is:

I messed with this for like 20 minutes before simply restarting firewalld, and after the firewall restarted the ports were listed using --list-all

So, I hate to be this guy, but "turn it off and back on again" seemed to be the fix here for me.